# How can I add numbers into a countdown timer so it counts a different number each time it finishes?

Tags: android, countdown

Basically I have made a countdown timer using android, the CountDownTimer class, a TextView and a button. It all works fine.

My problem is that I want my countdown timer to change its time each time one of the countdowns has finished.

For example: The countdown timer starts of by counting down from 5 minutes, now once that countdown has finished I want the countdown to automatically start again but from a different time say 1 minute and it continues like that.

So it should go 5 minutes then 1 minute then say 2 minutes and then 30 seconds then stop. Here is how the time is defined already:

```
    counter = new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            tv.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

        }

        public void onFinish(){

            System.out.println("Finished");

        }

    };
```

The 300000 is the milliseconds it counts down from so therefore 5 minutes and the 1000 is the  countdown interval, so 1 second.

So now the question remains: are there any ways to make it start counting down from 5 minutes then automatically start a countdown from a minute then 2 minutes then 30 seconds as an example?

I have tried using an array so here is the code I used but the for loop was too fast.

The array:

```
    int[] week1day1 = {10000, 20000, 30000};
```

The loop:

```
    for (int arrayValue = -1; arrayValue < week1day1.length; arrayValue++) { 


                    maxTime = week1day1[arrayValue];    


                        counter.start();

                    tv.setText("Pause"); 

                            System.out.println("Array Value");

            }
```

In the logcat "Array Value" shows up twice and in the space of about 10 milliseconds.
So I think the loop is not waiting for the maxTime to count down and therefore loops straight to the end of the array.

Comment: Could you post more code than just the call to the constructor? Perhaps that would make it easier to help.

Comment: Check the main thread, I hope that helps.

Comment: That loop wont work. If you don't need too many different count down values then you can define one CountDownTimer for each different value. Start the first count down. When it finishes so will the onFinish() method run so you can start start the next count down inside of it. Then you launch the third count down inside onFinish() of the second CountDownTimer and so on. Ugly solution though :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your program loop:

```
if(counter.count == 0)
{
    switch(counterMax)
    {
        case 1: counter = new CountDownTimer(maxTime1, countDownInterval1);
        case 2: counter = new CountDownTimer(maxTime2, countDownInterval2);
        // and so on
    }
    // put your "timer picker" code here
}
```

Hope this helps, likely will not work as typed (not looking at the docs), but it should give you a start.

Comment: Thank you! i'm fairly new in android programming so I was wondering is it also possible to use an array to set the maxTime? I will test now. By the way what do you mean by "//put your "timer picker" code here"?

Comment: You mentioned you wanted several different times available for your timer.  Put your logic to select these times there.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply! What do you mean by "Put your logic to select these times there."? By the way I have updated the main thread with more code in case it helps you. I was thinking though is there anyway I could make an array and pass the value to the maxTime?

Comment: You can do it however you like.  That part is up to you. :)

Comment: Mmmm Its just I have tried to iterate through the arrays numbers in a for loop. It worked its just the loop didn't wait until the number it got from the array had finished counting down, so it looped really quickly to the end of the array and then counted down the last number in the array. Give me a second and i'll update the main thread with an example.

Comment: You likely want to use a background service if you're iterating though this.'

Comment: oh so like get the array from a randomnamehere.xml?

Comment: I suggest you give it a try rather than asking me! :)  That's the best way to learn.

Comment: I've been trying for the last like 4 days... :D